# Workflow send an email with a list of items

Tags: 2013, list, workflow, email, view

In Sharepoint I have a simple custom list, which has the following columns: task name; task status (started, ongoing, finished); finished date. By using a custom view of this list, I can filter out my task list and see only the tasks, that were finished during, for example, last week. Is there any way to create a workflow that would send an email with a list of finished items during a certain period? (the list in an email should look similar to what you see in the custom list view part in sharepoint)

In other words - can you create a workflow to send an email, which would contain the same information that you can see in a custom list view?

I know there is a way to just send a link to a specific list view, but is there a way to cram the contents of a view into an email without doing a copy&paste manually?